# How to display data-Binding or Override ToString() C# WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have this Order class and I am using MVVM:

```
namespace drinksMVVM.Models
{
    public class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
    private Item _OrderItem;
    private ObservableCollection<Item> _Supplements;
    private double _OrderPrice;

    public Item OrderItem
    {
        get
        {
            return _OrderItem;
        }
        set
        {
            _OrderItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("OrderItem");
            _OrderPrice += _OrderItem.Price;
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Supplements
    {
        get
        {
            return _Supplements;
        }
        set
        {
            _Supplements = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Supplements");
            foreach(var supplement in _Supplements)
            {
                _OrderPrice += supplement.Price;
            }
        }
    }

    public double OrderPrice
    {
        get
        {
            return _OrderPrice;
        }
        set
        {
            _OrderPrice = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Price");
        }
    }

    public Order()
    {

    }

    public Order(Item item, ObservableCollection<Item> items)
    {
        _OrderItem = item;
        _Supplements = items;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
}
```

It contains object from type Item(properties Name and Price) and ObservableCollection of type Item. The Order object certainly contains one Item which is a single food/drink as order, but can contain Item and ObservableCollection, which is a food/drink with additional supplements.

Simple example:
I have order of Coffee with Sugar and Cream and I want to display them something like that:
Coffee (OrderItem)
Sugar+Cream (Supplements)
1,50 (OrderPrice)
The layout does not matter in this case

My question here is how to display the data in my view. I have two ideas which don't know how to continue.

1. DataTemplate with textblocks, each textblock is bind to a property of the Order class, but don't know how to display every single item name from the ObservableCollection.

   ```
   <DataTemplate x:Key="OrderTemplate">
       <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
           <TextBlock x:Name="OrderName" Text="{Binding OrderItem.Name}"/>
           <TextBlock x:Name="OrderSupplements" 
            Text="{Binding Supplements[0].Name}"/> ///Can't solve this
            binding 
           <TextBlock x:Name="OrderPrce" Text="{Binding OrderPrice}"/>
       </StackPanel>
   </DataTemplate>
   ```

2.Override the ToString() method of the Order class in order to display all of the data in one single textblock, but also can't find a solution how to display all supplements names.

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return OrderItem.Name + " " +/*every single supplement name*/+" "
        +OrderPrice.ToString();
    }
```

And

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="OrderTemplate1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="test" Text="{Binding}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Your question is too broad and lacks a good [mcve] as well. Typically, one uses `ItemsControl` or one of its subclasses (like `ListBox`) to display collections like `ObservableCollection<T>`. You could instead use `IValueConverter` to combine the elements into a single string, but then you wouldn't get property-change updates automatically. Please research available techniques and post a new question if you get to a point where you can provide a good [mcve] and a _specific_ question about how to implement the techniques you've researched.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am currently reading and trying to understand how the IValueConverter works.I am using the idea of combining the elements into single string. The override method had the same idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as option #2 goes...

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string orderStr = string.Empty;
    orderStr += _OrderItem.Name + " ";

    foreach(Item supplement in Supplements)
    {
        orderStr += supplement.Name + " ";
    }

    orderStr += OrderPrice.ToString();
    return orderStr;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it finally works great, I was having trouble with the foreach loop part.

Comment: You're very welcome. Thank you for the opportunity to help! Could you please mark my answer as the accepted one if it worked for you? Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve option #1 with IValueConverter

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(List<Item>),typeof(string))]
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        List<Item> items = (List<Item>)value;
        string supplementsString = string.Empty;
        if (items.Count >= 1)
        {
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                supplementsString += item.Name + " " + item.Price.ToString() + " " + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
        return supplementsString;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And XAML part

```
<converters:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverterTest"/>

<TextBlock x:Name="OrderSupplements" 
     Text="{Binding Supplements, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```